# Aggregate time between alternate rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset that's roughly 200KB in size. I've cleaned up the data and loaded it into an RDD in Spark (using pyspark) so that the header format is the following:

```
Employee ID | Timestamp (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM) | Location
```

This dataset stores employee stamp-in and stamp-out times, and I need to add up the amount of time that they've spent at work. Assuming the format of the rows is clean and strictly alternate (so stamp in, stamp out, stamp in, stamp out, etc), is there a way to aggregate the time spent in Spark?

I've tried using filters on all the "stamp in" values and aggregating the time with the value in the row directly after (so r+1) but this is proving to be very difficult not to mention expensive. I think this would be straightforward to do in a language like java or python, but before switching over am I missing a solution that can be implemented in Spark?

Comment: Assuming there is at most 2 timestamps for a given day and employee, you could create an additional column for the date of the timestamp.  Then do a groupby on employee and date.  Now, the stamp-in and stamp-out are in the same row and calculating the difference within a spark RDD is trivial.

Comment: @mrwyatt There aren't just two times per date, but I still did a groupby on employee name and date to make iterating through the data easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the window function [`lead`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lead):

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")
newDf = df.withColumn("stampOut", lead("timestamp", 1).over(window)).where(col("stampOut").isNotNull())

finalDf = newDf.select(col("id"), col("stampOut") - col("timestamp"))
```